# Error importing some Visualization Helium Packages in Zeppelin

Tags: highcharts, npm, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to import some helium packages into Zeppelin using this url.
https://zeppelin.apache.org/helium_packages.html

While some visualizations work fine like zeppelin-bubblechart , 
zeppelin-highcharts-spline some packages get installed(For example, zeppelin-highcharts-bubble) and I see the symbol in helium but it does not appear in my Zeppelin note when I execute the query.

What would be the reason for this?

Comment: JavaScript Console shall give some hint

Comment: Which version of Zeppelin are you using?

Comment: I am using zeppelin-0.7.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured out the solution.

For the packages like zeppelin-bubblechart the installation is direct where it is mentioned that we need to create a .json file under helium folder and takes care of it. Whereas the other installations are a bit different like for the zeppelin-highcharts-bubble. For packages like this to work,

- First we need to first install npm.
- Once you have npm installed, you could load packages via npm into helium and use them in Zeppelin.
- Go to the folder zeppelin-0.7.0-bin-all/local-repo/vis/node_modules and do npm i zeppelin-highcharts-bubble
- Then go to the folder zeppelin-highcharts-bubble and cp zeppelin-highcharts-bubble.json zeppelin-0.7.0-bin-all/helium/
- change the artifact in this file to zeppelin-highcharts-bubble@0.0.2 
  which is the _id from package.json under the folder zeppelin-0.7.0-bin-all/local-repo/vis/node_modules/zeppelin-highcharts-bubble
- Refresh the helium interface on Zeppelin and this should work.